# Ruby Modulo Division

Tags: ruby, modulo

So I made a program to do modulo division in Ruby, using a module:

```
module Moddiv
    def Moddiv.testfor(op1, op2)
        return op1 % op2
    end
end
```

Program:

```
require 'mdivmod'
print("Enter the first number: ")
gets
chomp
firstnum = $_
print("Enter the second number: ")
gets
chomp
puts
secondnum = $_
puts "The remainder of 70/6 is " + Moddiv.testfor(firstnum,secondnum).to_s
```

When I run it with two numbers, say 70 and 6, I get 70 as the output! Why is this happening?

Comment: sscce.org.  Also, are you sure this is a question about Rails?  Just looks like Ruby to me.

Comment: Yeah its just ruby, i was distracted, typed rails instead, sorry, edited

Comment: Try simplifying your code and posting the whole thing here.  You can simplify it to 1 line.

Comment: If you simplify it you'll probably find the bug.  I'm not sure what the bug is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because `firstnum` and `secondnum` are the *strings* `"70"` and `"6"`. And `String#%` is defined - it's the formatted-output operator.

Since `"70"` is not a format string, it's treated as a literal; so `"70" % "6"` prints "6" formatted according to the template `"70"`, which is just `"70"`.

You need to convert your input with `firstnum = $_.to_i` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Modulo seems to have trouble with strings, for example, in irb:

```
"70" % "6" => "70"
```

try making your return statement:

```
return op1.to_i % op2.to_i
```

Comment: @Chowlett has a better explanation (and beat me by 21 seconds!)

Answer (score 0):

You're grabbing user input as strings, not integers.

```
"70" % "6"
# => "70"

70 % 6
# => 4
```

Use `.to_i` on your parameters and you should be good to go.