# The code always outputs "not"

Tags: ruby

The following code always outputs "not":

```
print "input a number please. "
TestNumber = gets
if TestNumber % 2 == 0
  print "The number is even"
else
  print "The number is not even"
end
```

What is going wrong with my code?

Comment: is #!/usr/bin/ruby there? . Can you even do puts "done"? is it executable?

Comment: @sawa: Please, be careful with your edits. The question originally stated that it always prints "The number is not even". After your edit, the question states that it doesn't print anything. That is a *totally different problem*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Sorry about that, and thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gets()` method returns an object of type `String`.

When you call `%()` on a `String` object, the return value is a new `String` object (usually it changes the text. [You can read more about string formatting here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-25)).

Since there are no `String` objects that `== 0`, the if/else will always take the same path.

If you want to use the return value of `gets()` like a number, you will need to transform it into one first. The simplest approach is probably to use the `to_i()` method on `String` objects, which returns a new 'Integer' object. If you're doing something where the user input will not always be an integer (e.g. `3.14` or `1.5`), you might need to use a different approach.

One last thing: in your example the result of `gets()` is saved into a `constant` called `TestNumber`. Constants are different to normal variables, and they will probably cause problems if you're not using them intentionally. Normal variables don't start with capital letters. ([You can read more about ruby variables here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm)). In ruby you need to write you variable names like this: `test_number`.

Comment: The question title initially indicated that the example code always printed "The number is not even".

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your Testnumber variable might be interpreted as a string during the operation. make sure the testnum is converted to an integer first even if you put in say 100 it could be its being interpreted as the stirng "100" and not the integer 100.

A similar issue can be found here: [Ruby Modulo Division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808357/ruby-modulo-division)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert TestNumber from string to integer, as your input has linefeed and/or other unwanted characters that do not match an integer.

Use `TestNumber = gets.to_i` to convert to integer before testing.